# Powermockito: how to 'release' a class annotated with @PrepareForTest?

Tags: testng, mockito, powermock

i have a class e.g. ExampleClass consisting of static functions. For testing in another class it is mocked by powermock with the @PrepareForTest annotation and then mocked by mockStatic.

The test class for ExampleClass itself also extends PowerMockTestCase to statically mock 3rd party libraries.

Now the problem is, that these tests are not run anymore by our code coverage tool. I suspect that the ExampleClass is somehow 'hidden' by the @PrepareForTest annotation. So after running the test class i would like to do something like 'release' the annotated class or remove it from the powermockito class loader. 
How can this be done?

somehow 'release' the class

Comment: Is EclEmma your code coverage tool?  If so, this is a known problem that won't likely ever be fixed.

Comment: We use JaCoco - so it is from the EclEmma team at least. Have you reference links/bug entries addressing this problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: This might provide some info: https://github.com/jacoco/eclemma/issues/15 .

Answer (score 0):

I think your concern is that all your unit tests might run in the same class loader due to which the PowerMock-manipulated ExampleClass class might affect other unit tests as well. In this case, you can try:

- Using PowerMock's [Java agent](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/PowerMockAgent) that bootstraps using the Java instrumentation API instead of classloader OR
- Implement a JUnitRunner that executes each test in a separate classloader. Check this [thread](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/issues/245).

I think JUnit uses separate classloaders for tests but I couldn't find any authoritative source for that.

Comment: Thank you very much. Though we use TestNG instead of jUnit, but the first approach deals with it too. :)